# Can I convert Eigen::VectorXi to Eigen::VectorXd?

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

I am using RcppEigen on R.
I would like to take a double vector from R layer:

```
RcppExport SEXP testfunc (SEXP a) {
    const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> vecD(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(a));
```

But, number is comming as integer, so I need to get it as integer like this :

```
RcppExport SEXP testfunc (SEXP a) {
    const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> vecD(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> >(a));
```

So, I need to convert it to the double. Can I convert Eigen::VectorXi to  Eigen::VectorXd ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are not getting confused calling with `integer` from R when you meant `numeric` aka `double` or vice versa ?   There is no reason not to have two functions, or to dispatch inside your function.

Eg consider the code here (using Rcpp 0.10.0 features)

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double vecdSum(SEXP x) {
    const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> 
       vec(Rcpp::as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(x));
    return vec.sum();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int veciSum(SEXP x) {
    const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> 
       vec(Rcpp::as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> >(x));
    return vec.sum();
}
```

which we can easily put to use via

```
R> sourceCpp('/tmp/vecsums.cpp')    # Rcpp 0.10.0 adds this
R> veciSum(c(1L, 2L, 3L))
[1] 6
R> vecdSum(c(1, 2, 3))
[1] 6
R>
```

Comment: It's fantastic, sourceCpp() !

Comment: You want `rep(0L, 5)` instead.

Comment: I have integer-vector-data and numeric-vector-data from data files. They are needed to sum and divide each other. How can I solve it?

Comment: integer(5) is an example.. I have very large integer-vector-data.